# update row where first character is L

Tags: mysql

How can I update all rows where a value in a specific column starts with the letter L ?

How can I update all rows where a value in a specific column starts with the letter L ?

Answer (score 0):

`UPDATE tbl SET col1 = 'foo', col2 = 'bar' WHERE marked_col LIKE 'L%'`

This is one of many ways to do so, but it may be the most efficient.